# How can I select all rows and columns from a matrix by matching with another data frame in R?

Tags: r, matrix, match

imagine you have a matrix of 2000 rows and 2000 columns in R. Both (rownames and column names are identical). Now I have another data frame with 380 rows and one column. I would like to know how it is possible to select the rows and columns from the big matrix which match to the 380 values? 
I hope you can help.

Best wishes,

Lukas

Comment: you could ``merge()`` your data or use the ``match()`` function. Please share your data and what you tried so far.

Comment: I have already tried that one: 
matrix[(match(matrix, df2)),]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. (Include a smaller data set than your own for testing)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, here is an example of how you could create a second column in the dataframe with the matching value from the matrix.

```
A<-matrix(c(1:16), nrow = 4)
colnames(A)<-c("a","b","c","d")
rownames(A)<-c("a","b","c","d")
b<-as.data.frame(matrix(c("a","b","c","d")))

for (i in 1:nrow(B)){
  b[i,2]<-A[b[i,1],b[i,1]]
}

b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but I want as output a matrix again, with the rows and the columns of the matched values. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I may not be understanding. I thought you wanted the value from the cell of the matrix that has the column and row names that match the value in the cell of the dataframe.

Comment: Are you saying you want to subset the original matrix to only include values that match the dataframe?

Comment: `A<-matrix(c(1:16), nrow = 4)`
`colnames(A)<-c("a","b","c","d")`
`rownames(A)<-c("a","b","c","d")`
`b<-as.data.frame(matrix(c("a","b","c")))`
Use column one of dataframe to provide names of columns and rows you want from matrix A to be in matrix C.
`C<-A[as.character(b[,1]),as.character(b[,1])]`

Comment: Yes exactly, I only want to subset the original matrix to only include values that match the data frame.

Comment: This Should do it `Output<-Original_Matrix[as.character(Original_Dataframe[,1]),as.character(Original_Dataframe[,1])]`.